# PHP - Substring after X characters with special-characters

Tags: php, special-characters

Sorry for the title, I really didn't know how to say this...

I often have a string that needs to be cut after X characters, my problem is that this string often contains special characters like : & egrave ;

So, I'm wondering, is their a way to know in php, without transforming my string, if when I am cutting my string, I am in the middle of a special char.

**Example**

```
This is my string with a special char : &egrave; - and I want it to cut in the middle of the "&egrave;" but still keeping the string intact
```

so right now my result with a sub string would be :

```
This is my string with a special char : &egra
```

but I want to have something like this :

```
This is my string with a special char : &egrave;
```

Comment: what should happen is your count is in the middle of a normal word?

Comment: @Cfreak we cut the word... (and we want to cut it)

Comment: well the issue is that in a normal string like this `&egrave;` is the same as any other word. There's nothing special about it. You could parse it or use a regex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best thing to do here is store your string as UTF-8 without any html entities, and use the `mb_*` family of functions with `utf8` as the encoding.

But, if your string is ASCII or iso-8859-1/win1252, you can use the special `HTML-ENTITIES` encoding of the mb_string library:

```
$s = 'This is my string with a special char : &egrave; - and I want it to cut in the middle of the "&egrave;" but still keeping the string intact';
echo mb_substr($s, 0, 40, 'HTML-ENTITIES');
echo mb_substr($s, 0, 41, 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

However, **if your underlying string is UTF-8 or some other multibyte encoding**, using `HTML-ENTITIES` is **not safe**! This is because `HTML-ENTITIES` really means "win1252 with high-bit characters as html entities".  This is an example of where this can go wrong:

```
// Assuming that é is in utf8:
mb_substr('é ', 0, 2, 'HTML-ENTITIES') === '&Atilde;&copy;'
// should be '&eacute; '
```

When your string is in a multibyte encoding, you must instead convert all html entities to a common encoding before you split. E.g.:

```
$strings_actual_encoding = 'utf8';
$s_noentities = html_entity_decode($s, ENT_QUOTES, $strings_actual_encoding); 
$s_trunc_noentities =  mb_substr($s_noentities, 0, 41, $strings_actual_encoding);
```

Comment: I would appreciate to know why : , if your underlying string is UTF-8 or some other multibyte encoding, using HTML-ENTITIES is not safe!.

Comment: @Hipny, by itself it isn't safe. You have to specify the encoding manually as the third parameter of [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) and [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Comment: The `HTML-ENTITIES` pseudo-encoding really means "win-1252/iso-8859-1 plus code high-bit characters as html entities". If you use it with a multibyte encoding, it may chop characters in half and convert them into entities. E.g.: `mb_substr('é ', 0, 2, 'HTML-ENTITIES')==='&Atilde;&copy;'`

Answer (score 4):

The *best* solution would be to store your text as UTF-8, instead of storing them as HTML entities. Other than that, if you don't mind the count being off (`&grave;` equals one character, instead of 7), then the following snippet should work:

```
<?php
$string = 'This is my string with a special char : &egrave; - and I want it to cut in the middle of the "&egrave;" but still keeping the string intact';
$cut_string = htmlentities(mb_substr(html_entity_decode($string, NULL, 'UTF-8'), 0, 45), NULL, 'UTF-8')."<br><br>";
```

***Note:** If you use a different function to encode the text (e.g. `htmlspecialchars()`), then use that function instead of `htmlentities()`. If you use a custom function, then use another custom function that does the opposite of your new custom function instead of `html_entity_decode()` (and custom function instead of `htmlentities()`).*

Answer (score 3):

You can use html_entity_decode() first to decode all the HTML entities.  Then split your string. Then htmlentities() to re-encode the entities.

```
$decoded_string = html_entity_decode($original_string);
// implement logic to split string here

// then for each string part do the following:
$encoded_string_part = htmlentities($split_string_part);
```

Comment: +1 - I was going to post just this (with an example though). Would you add and example too?

Comment: Good answer but could be slower than other solution if we were working with a 10000000 words string

Comment: But if he's after say the first 100 characters of the original string, after decoding the entities, he's including more text of the original string that may not be desired. For each 10 character "special character" that's decoded, there's 9 more characters from the original string being added. ie "&amp;" is four characters and "&" is 1.

Comment: This is great when you can count on responsible of not mixture of things like `"something&quot;` due to [`ENT_QUOTES`](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)...

But still, if I'll give you string like `n&aacute;n&aacute;n&aacute; Batman`... The result would be much longer then desired.

Answer (score 3):

The longest HTML entity is 10 characters long, including the ampersand and semicolon. If you intend to cut the string at `X` bytes, check bytes `X-9` through `X-1` for an ampersand. If the corresponding semicolon appears at byte `X` or later, cut the string after the semicolon instead of after byte `X`.

However, if you're willing to preprocess the string, Mike's solution will be more accurate because his cuts the string at `X` *characters*, not bytes.

Comment: This is the best solution right now ;) I will wait 10-15 mins and if their isn't any better solution, I will mark you as accepted ;)

Comment: This solution does not take into account the dangers involved in splitting a string in a multibyte encoding.

Comment: Looping 10 chars from the end is probably more effective way to do this than my solution ;) +1, but could you please provide source for *The longest HTML entity is 10 characters long*?

Comment: @Vyktor, the longest symbol defined in [the W3C's reference page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html) is `&thetasym;`.

Comment: @FrancisAvila, that is correct, but I'm assuming that any multibyte characters are converted to HTML entities in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

A little bruteforce solution, that I'm not really happy with would a `PCRE` expression, let's say that you want to pass 80 characters and the longest possible HTML expression is 7 chars long:

```
$regex = '~^(.{73}([^&]{7}|.{0,7}$|[^&]{0,6}&[^;]+;))(.*)~mx'
// Note, this could return a bit of shorter text
return preg_replace( $regexp, '$1', $text);
```

Just so you know:

- `.{73}` - 73 characters
- `[^&]{7}` - okay, we may fill it with anything that doesn't contain &
- `.{0,7}$` - keep in mind the possible end (this shouldn't be necessary because shorter text wouldn't match at all)
- `[^&]{0,6}&[^;]+;` - up to 6 characters (you'd be at 79th), then `&` and let it finish

Something that seems much better but requires bit of play with numbers is to:

```
// check whether $text is at least $N chars long :)
if( strlen( $text) < $N){
    return;
}

// Get last &
$pos = strrpos( $text, '&', $N);

// We're not young anymore, we have to check this too (not entries at all) :)
if( $pos === false){
    return substr( $text, 0, $N);
}

// Get Last
$end = strpos( $text, ';', $N);

// false wouldn't be smaller then 0 (entry open at the beginning
if( $end === false){
    $end = -1;
}

// Okay, entry closed (; is after &)(
if( $end > $pos){
   return substr($text, 0, $N);
}

// Now we need to find first ;
$end = strpos( $text, ';', $N)
if( $end === false){
    // Not valid HTML, not closed entry, do whatever you want
}

return substr($text, 0, $end);
```

<sub>Check numbers, there may be +/-1 somewhere in indexes...</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to use a combination of strpos and strrpos to find the next and previous spaces, parse the text between the spaces, check that against a known list of special characters, and if it matches, extend your "cut" to the position of the next space. If you had a code sample of what you have now, we could give you a better answer.